# After upgrading: rCharts not working in rmarkdown

Tags: r, rcharts

after I upgraded to `rCharts` version  0.4.5 I am not able to see a plot in my rmarkdown file anymore. I have produced a minimum example rmd where I cannot see the plots anymore (if I open the output in my browser). I have absolutely no clue which package is responsible for this. Note that it works fine if I use the `$save` mode and just import the created html file as in example number 2.

Do you have any idea?

I created a minimum example from a highcharts demo. [This thread](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/492) also helped me.

````
```{r echo = F, message = F, cache = F}
# Set options for plots.
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(results = 'asis', comment = NA, message = F, tidy = F, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(rCharts)
a <- hPlot(Pulse ~ Height, data = MASS::survey, type = "bubble", title = "Zoom demo", subtitle = "bubble chart", size = "Age", group = "Exer")
a$chart(zoomType = "x")
a$exporting(enabled = T)
a$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(rCharts)
a <- hPlot(Pulse ~ Height, data = MASS::survey, type = "bubble", title = "Zoom demo", subtitle = "bubble chart 2", size = "Age", group = "Exer")
a$chart(zoomType = "x")
a$exporting(enabled = T)
a$save('plot2.html', standalone = TRUE)
```
<iframe src="plot2.html" height="450" width="850" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
````

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a new "feature", that transforms links of e.g. sources starting with `http://www.` as `//www.` to make it also work with `https://`. On webservers, this is interpreted correctly but if you open a local html file, `//www.` will not be recognized. The issue is reported on the [github](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/589#issuecomment-101580528) page.